# How to use ical4j with a caldav server?

Tags: java, caldav, ical4j

I'm using ical4j 3.2.14 to add, update or delete events on a file based calendar and it works fine. The next step is doing the same on a caldav server like sogo.
I know ical4j-connector but I've got no idea how to use it. I couldn't find any usefull tutorial or example for that.

Could someone explain me how to read a calendar object from a caldav server and merge or save the changes back?

Every hint is helpful.